# Why is Django forms fields value not rendering in html template for function based update view?

Tags: python, django, view, instance

The issue is when i try to update my profile, i do not see the exising value i do not actually know what is wrong with the views..

views.py

```
def profile_update(request):
    info = Announcements.objects.filter(active=True)
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Acount Updated Successfully!')
            return redirect('profile', profile.user.username)
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
    
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'info': info,
        'categories': categories
    }

    return render(request, 'userauths/profile_update.html', context)
```

Comment: Don't pass data to the forms when the method is GET

Comment: @lain-shelvington okay, but is that going to be cause why the existing user information are not been filled in

Comment: Yes, when you pass data and an instance to a ModelForm the passed data takes precedence over the existing values from the instance. When you__only__ pass an instance the existing values from the instance are used as initial data

Comment: remove the `Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)` line, it may harm your code execution; in the previous line you get the profile object or throw a 404 error if  `profile` does not exist. So no need to `get_or_create` the `profile`  object. The `get_or_create` function is little bit complex, use it after knowing about this function correctly.

Comment: @lain-Shelvington please what do you recommend me to do, can you please show me some code, i'm a django beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your form = UpdateFormExample(request.POST, instance=request.user)
this fixed the issue